# Visual Studio ASP.NET Launch settings

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

can someone explain whats the difference between these settings?
[image]

The reason im asking: default pick was IIS Express and multiple processes used my logger and created duplicates in the log. But when i picked Project, there were no duplicates in the log.

Answer (score 0):

The first is IIS Express that will use IIS Express to host this project and the second is `Project` that will run this project and debugging it.

If your project include `Main` that you can select `Project` to Launch and VisualStudio will debugging it.

The last one is `Executable` that will use the other application to run this project like `dotnet run xx.dll` and you should set the running application path when you select `Executable` and set some arguments. The VisualStudio will debugging the running application like use attached process.

See:[Working with Environments and Launch Settings in ASP.NET Core](https://exceptionnotfound.net/working-with-environments-and-launch-settings-in-asp-net-core/)

[Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.1)